# Not able to debug Sitecore solution from Visual Studio

Tags: helix, visual-studio, debug

Our Sitecore solution is on Helix architecture and JSS. Published Foundation, Feature, Project dlls and referenced dlls also. I'm trying to debug one rendering content resolver but the breakpoint is not hitting. On hover of breakpoint, says symbols are not loaded.

1. Solution is in Debug mode only and not in Release mode.
2. Latest dlls are published and available in bin folder.
3. There is no rendering cache enabled in Sitecore.
4. Everytime I try to debug, have to manually load symbols for the dlls.

Can you please help me to identify why symbols are not getting loaded automatically?
[image]

Comment: Try out this solution https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/cannot-get-debugger-to-attach-to-code-for-new-module-project-deployed-to-new-sit/35808#35808

Comment: Yes, tried all the steps mentioned. But no success, facing same issue.

Comment: are you running locally or in Docker?

Comment: It's in local only. Docker is also not installed in local.

Comment: If you have solution on local IIS, you need to in visual studio to attach to process and choose w3wp.exe. I never debugged other way.

Comment: what's the yellow warning on that breakpoint?

Comment: Yellow warning- 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.' 

But latest dlls are available in bin folder.

Comment: Yes always used to debug by attaching to w3wp.exe process. First time facing this issue where symbols are not loaded automatically.